# iOS Swift Facebook AccountKit doesn't logout properly

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, account-kit

I've just integrated Facebook's **AccountKit** to use the SMS login feature and everything works fine but I have 2 problems when I'm trying to log out:

**First:**

I get this error in the logout completion handler (but I can make the log out "work" if I set the `Require App Secret` to NO on my app's Facebook page in AccountKit settings)

> Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.accountkit:Error Code=200 \"(null)\" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x281c64900 {Error Domain=com.facebook.accountkit:ServerError Code=145 \"(null)\" UserInfo={com.facebook.accountkit:ErrorDeveloperMessageKey=API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument}}, com.facebook.accountkit:ErrorDeveloperMessageKey=API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument})

**Second:**

After logout was done the `currentAccessToken` isn't set to nil so when I kill the app and relaunch it I still have the old accessToken.

Comment: I've sent a bug report to Facebook

Comment: happening to mine too

Comment: @myatmins no news from them yet... making it work with `Required App Secret` to `NO` for the moment ..